# How to get express-basic-auth to prompt a popup for user and password?

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

I have a node.js app that used to work when basicAuth was a module of node. Below code would popup a password and username prompt when visiting app.

```
// start the UI
var app = express();
app.use(express.basicAuth('me', 'openforme'));
app.use(kue.app);
app.listen(3001);
```

Now that basicAuth was removed as a module, from node, I am using express-basic-auth. When using the below code I get a 401 unauthorized error because it is not giving me a username and password popup prompt like basicAuth did?

```
// start the UI
var app = express();
var basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'me': 'openforme' }
}));
app.use(kue.app);
app.listen(3001);
```

Answer (score 32):

Now there is an out-of-the-box option from `express-basic-auth`. The [Challenge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth#challenge) property.

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    challenge: true,
    users: { 'me': 'openforme' }
}));
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks very much!   I'm wondering why official document do not mention this.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is very late to the party, but your desired behavior can be achieved by using `basic-auth` like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const auth = require('basic-auth')
const app = express()

// Ensure this is before any other middleware or routes
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let user = auth(req)

  if (user === undefined || user['name'] !== 'USERNAME' || user['pass'] !== 'PASSWORD') {
    res.statusCode = 401
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Node"')
    res.end('Unauthorized')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```